# How to receive an unknown length data using UART in an array and store it & receive next set of data, without deleting what's in the first register?

Tags: c, stm32, uart

I have to receive an unknown length of data from a UART Interrupt serial communication. I have initialized an array, to store the data. Now, when I receive the data and store it byte by byte until the user enters \n, the data should be stored, and not overwritten when a new set of data comes in. For this, I thought of initializing a counter, whenever there is data received, the counter should increment, and the data to be stored in the next register. Since I am very new to programming and I need to code this C language for STM32, how do I do this?

```
uint8_t rx_data [200];
int count = 0;
    void HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart)
{

    HAL_UART_Receive_IT (&huart2, rx_data);
    count ++;
}
```

Comment: You may wish to read about [circular buffers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer).

Comment: You couldn't use the CubeMX functions to receive an unknown length. (The HAL will disable the interface after each character and that could lead to character loss)
You will have to use the LowLevel interface to continuously receive data.

Comment: @theSealion what are you talking about? You can receive an unknown amount of data. You just have to chunk it per byte.

Comment: @TarickWelling yes and after each byte the USART is disabled by the HAL. And enabled again if you want to receive the next byte. And this could lead to missed characters (depending on the baudrate).

Comment: @theSealion no it doesn't. So please show me a bit of code from the HAL that does, so you can prove your point.

Comment: @TarickWelling Ok, it was not the enable but the RXNE IRQ that is clear after the desired amount of data is received
`/* Disable the UART Parity Error Interrupt and RXNE interrupt*/
CLEAR_BIT(huart->Instance->CR1, (USART_CR1_RXNEIE | USART_CR1_PEIE));`
(Line 2406 from stm32f4xx_hal_uart.c)

Answer (score 3):

Well,the best way is two buffers and FreeRTOS.
The problem is that you may not receive one by one, but can get number of bytes at one time. So you need two buffers: "receive buffer" and "data buffer". Also you may need some kind of "clear buffer" to empty your others buffers. That is faster then empty buffer in cycle.

So.Let's see. I write example for STM32F303. First of all create a task for FreeRTOS in CubeMX, let it be **consoleTaskHandle**. Then add or edit in **stm32f3xx_it.c**:

```c
/* Private includes -----------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */
#include "cmsis_os.h"
/* USER CODE END Includes */

//........................
//........................

/* USER CODE BEGIN EV */
extern osThreadId consoleTaskHandle;
/* USER CODE END EV */

//........................
//........................

/**
* @brief This function handles USART2 global interrupt
*/
void USART2_IRQHandler(void) {
    /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_IRQn 0 */
    BaseType_t xHigherPriorityTaskWoken;
    xHigherPriorityTaskWoken = pdFALSE;

    vTaskNotifyGiveFromISR(consoleTaskHandle, &xHigherPriorityTaskWoken);

    portYIELD_FROM_ISR(xHigherPriorityTaskWoken);
    /* USER CODE END USART2_IRQn 0 */
    HAL_UART_IRQHandler(&huart2);
    /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_IRQn 1 */

    /* USER CODE END USART2_IRQn 1 */
}
```

That means, that every time IT executes we will send notification to FreeRTOS task.

Now, let's write task to work with our recieved data. So **main.c**:

```c
/* Private includes ----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
/* USER CODE END Includes */

//........................
//........................

/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PD */
/* USART */
#define USART_CONSOLE_BUFFER_SIZE ((uint8_t)64)
/* USER CODE END PD */

//........................
//........................

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */
/* USART */
static const char emptyBuffer[USART_CONSOLE_BUFFER_SIZE] = {0x00};
char consoleRxBuffer[USART_CONSOLE_BUFFER_SIZE] = {0x00};
char consoleTxBuffer[USART_CONSOLE_BUFFER_SIZE] = {0x00};
/* USER CODE END PV */

//........................
//........................

/* USER CODE BEGIN Header_StartConsoleTask */
/**
* @brief Function implementing the consoleTask thread.
* @param argument: Not used
* @retval None
*/
/* USER CODE END Header_StartConsoleTask */
void StartConsoleTask(void const * argument) {
    /* USER CODE BEGIN StartConsoleTask */
    uint32_t ulNotifiedValue     = 0;
    static uint8_t rxBufferLen   = 0; /*!< Current RX buffer length */ 
    static uint8_t txBufferLen   = 0; /*!< Current TX buffer length */
    static uint8_t lastBufferLen = 0; /*!< Last RX buffer length */


    static bool gotCommand = false;  /*!< Recieved command flag */

    char command[USART_CONSOLE_BUFFER_SIZE] = {0x00}; /*!< Command buffer */

    if (HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart2, (uint8_t *)consoleRxBuffer, USART_CONSOLE_BUFFER_SIZE) != HAL_OK) {
        // Uart error handle
    }

    for (;;) {
        ulNotifiedValue = ulTaskNotifyTake(pdFALSE, (TickType_t) ULONG_MAX);

        // Got notification from IT
        if (ulNotifiedValue > 0) {
            // Let's check the RX buffer first
            rxBufferLen = strlen(consoleRxBuffer);

            if (rxBufferLen > 0) {
                // Let's send data back to console
                // or we gonna print data blindly
                if (rxBufferLen > lastBufferLen) {
                    /*
                        If the last symbol is '\r', then:
                            - Stop RX
                            - Send '\n' next
                            - Copy RX buffer to command buffer
                            - Empty RX buffer and start IT again
                            - Set 'GotCommand flag'
                        ELSE
                            - Simply send data back to cosole
                     */

                    // Count amount of data to send back
                    txBufferLen = rxBufferLen - lastBufferLen;

                    // Copy data from RX buffer to TX buffer
                    strncpy(consoleTxBuffer, &consoleRxBuffer[lastBufferLen], txBufferLen);
                    consoleTxBuffer[txBufferLen] = '\0';

                    if (consoleRxBuffer[rxBufferLen - 1] == '\r') {
                        gotCommand = true;

                        HAL_UART_AbortReceive_IT(&huart2);

                        consoleTxBuffer[txBufferLen] = '\n';
                        consoleTxBuffer[txBufferLen + 1] = '\0';

                        /* Copy command from RX buffer to command buffer */
                        // Let's trim spaces from the beginning
                        uint8_t commandStartPos = 0;

                        for (int i = 0; i < USART_CONSOLE_BUFFER_SIZE; ++i) {
                            if (consoleRxBuffer[0] == ' ') {
                                commandStartPos++;
                            } else {
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                        strncpy(command, &consoleRxBuffer[commandStartPos], strlen(consoleRxBuffer) - commandStartPos + 1);

                        /*
                            Empty RX buffer
                            I clean it by copying empty buffer to RX. That increases memory 
                            consumption, but works faster. You can do it in cycle.
                         */
                        strncpy(consoleRxBuffer, emptyBuffer, USART_CONSOLE_BUFFER_SIZE);

                        lastBufferLen = 0;

                        // Start the UART IT again
                        if (HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart2, (uint8_t *)consoleRxBuffer, USART_CONSOLE_BUFFER_SIZE) != HAL_OK) {
                            // Uart error handle
                        }

                    } else {
                        lastBufferLen = rxBufferLen;
                    }

                    // Send data back to console through UART DMA (you must turn it on in settings)
                    if (HAL_UART_Transmit_DMA(&huart2, (uint8_t *)consoleTxBuffer, strlen(consoleTxBuffer)) != HAL_OK) {
                        // Uart error handle
                    }

                    while (__HAL_UART_GET_FLAG(&huart2, UART_FLAG_TC) == RESET) {
                        vTaskDelay(1);
                    }
                }

                /* If we got command in last condition */
                if (gotCommand == true) {
                    gotCommand = false; // Reset flag

                    // Do some work with recieved command/data
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As far as I know, HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart2, (uint8_t *)consoleRxBuffer, USART_CONSOLE_BUFFER_SIZE) function doesn't trigger the interrupt until it receives the USART_CONSOLE_BUFFER_SIZE number of bytes. How can this handle variable length data?